# Scenarios for return values

Tags: c#

If no return value is found when it must be found, I return an exception.

If no value to be found is sometimes expected, I return null (this will avoid the assumption of a valid string when doing if (str != "")

Are these valid return scenarios for a method which returns a string?

Thanks

Comment: Well... Does the method do what you want it to do? If so, yes, it's valid.

Comment: I would return an empty string when it is valid that no value was found. Then, you only have to check the length of the returned string with if (foo.Length > 0). Alternately, you could use String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo) to catch both values. Either of these are better than str != "".

Comment: Yeah I always prefer string.IsNullOrEmpty, and make a point of using this.

Comment: It depends on the length of a piece of string. If the string is 10cm or longer, throw an exception. Otherwise return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally avoid using Exceptions for program flow in this way. Exceptions should be reserved for circumstances where you cannot continue.

Also, for string testing I'd use string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: We don't have enough information to know whether the value not being found indicates a significant error which *should* stop processing (in which case an exception is appropriate) or is a legitimate situation (in which case it wouldn't be).

Comment: Sure, but I would still rather throw in the code that requested the return value, not the code that retrieves it. YMMV.

Comment: It depends on the scenario. We simply don't have enough information here. If it's *always* an error, why force that check in every single caller? Would you want `File.Open` to return `null` if the file couldn't be found?

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on the design of your application, but in a (very) broad sense, yes, these return values make sense.

However, in either case, make sure you document all of the return cases clearly.